# Tight prime bounds

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

This is a cross-post of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865820/very-tight-prime-bounds) on MSE. I would not usually do this, but have decided to in this case since it has had no responses having been posted as a bounty question. I did not delete the MSE question since so many users have starred it (and are apparently interested in seeing it answered) and not all of those users will have an MO account. If it receives a positive response here, I intend to link it to the MSE question for the benefit of those users. If however, this is objected to by MO users, or is not deemed 'research level', I shall respectfully remove it.

The question is: Is it likely that

$$\left|\operatorname{li}(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor}\dfrac{\pi(n^{1/k})}{k}-\log(2)-\dfrac{1}{2}\right|<\dfrac{2\sqrt{n}}{e\log(n)}?$$

This is of course, almost identical to saying

$$|R(n)-\pi(n)|<\dfrac{2\sqrt{n}}{e\log(n)}$$ where $R$ is the Riemann prime counting function, but this is a little too tight since this doesn't hold for $n=113$. Since

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor}\dfrac{\pi(n^{1/k})}{k}\approx\operatorname{li}(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2\ \Re\left(\operatorname{Ei}\left(\rho_k\log\left(n\right)\right)\right)-\log(2)
$$

and since $\pm\dfrac{2\sqrt{n}}{\Im(\rho_1)\log(n)}$ bounds $2\ \Re\left(\operatorname{Ei}\left(\rho_1\log\left(n\right)\right)\right)$

does it follow that $\pm\dfrac{2\sqrt{n}}{C\log(n)}$ will bound $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2\ \Re\left(\operatorname{Ei}\left(\rho_k\log\left(n\right)\right)\right)$ for some $C$ (assuming RH)?

*$C=e$ seems particularly tight.* Is this a realistic bound to propose?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The inequality you propose would imply that
$$ |\operatorname{li}(n)-\pi(n)| \ll \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log n}. $$
On the other hand, Littlewood (1914) showed that this relation is false, in fact he proved that the left hand side divided by the right hand side is $\Omega(\log\log\log n)$.

So the inequality you propose is false.

**Added 1.** Littlewood's original paper is "Sur la distribution des nombres premiers", C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris, 158 (1914), 1869-1872. For a modern proof, see Theorem 15.11 in Montgomery-Vaughan's book "Multiplicative number theory I." (which is apparently the last result in the book).

**Added 2.** The OP asked in a comment how the inequality above follows from his proposed bound. Here are the details. We clearly have (for $n>100$)
$$ \operatorname{li}(n)-\pi(n) = S_1+\frac{\pi(n^{1/2})}{2} + S_2,$$
where
$$S_1:=\operatorname{li}(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor}\dfrac{\pi(n^{1/k})}{k}-\log(2)-\dfrac{1}{2}$$
$$S_2:=\sum_{k=3}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor}\dfrac{\pi(n^{1/k})}{k}+\log(2)+\dfrac{1}{2}.$$
The second expression $S_2$ is a sum of less than $\log n$ terms, each less than $n^{1/3}$. Hence, by the triangle inequality,
$ |S_2|\leq n^{1/3}\log n \ll \sqrt{n}/\log n$.
Using also the OP's conjecture $S_1\ll \sqrt{n}/\log n$ we get, again by the triangle inequality,
$$ |\operatorname{li}(n)-\pi(n)|\leq |S_1|+|\pi(n^{1/2})|+|S_2|\ll \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log n}.$$
This, on the other hand, contradicts Littlewood's result from 1914.

Comment: Great - thanks for your response. Could I ask for a reference here?

Comment: Do you know which paper it was?

Comment: @martin: I added the original reference and a pointer to a modern treatment.

Comment: Thank you - I imagine the modern treatment will be more accessible - I will try that one first. Again, many thanks for your answer.

Comment: please feel free to collect the bounty at mse

Comment: @martin: Thank you, but I am not registered there. On the other hand, please accept my answer here (so that it turns green).

Comment: Have just seen Littlewood's proof that you mentioned in Ingham - which I ordered today, coincidentally!

Comment: having looked at it, I don't see that one discounts the other. Am I wrong in coming to this conclusion?

Comment: @martin: Are you saying that the two proofs in Montgomery-Vaughan and Ingham are substantially different?

Comment: No, I am really questioning the use of Hardy & Littlewood's $\Omega$ notation, since it is very different to $O$ notation.

Comment: I am not sure whether the statement above completely discounts the limit suggested by Littlewood.

Comment: Incidentally, I can't find a link to "Sur la distribution des nombres premiers" anywhere

Comment: @martin: Hardy-Littlewood's $\Omega$ notation is the negation of $o$ (small oh), as usual in analytic number theory. So Littlewood really proves that the ratio of the two sides is not $o(\log\log\log n)$, in particular it is not $O(1)$ as would follow from your proposed inequality.

Comment: @martin: Regarding the link, I don't know about one either. You can read the paper in a library, or you can read a modern treatment in Montgomery-Vaughan. The $\Omega_\pm$ notation of Theorem 15.11 in that book is introduced at the bottom of page 5.

Comment: @ GH from MO, ok this helps, thank you - I will persevere

Comment: @martin: He proved more. He proved that there is a $C>0$ such that for infinitely many $n$'s we have $\pi(n)-\operatorname{li}(n)>C\sqrt{n}\log\log\log n/\log n$ and for infinitely many $n$'s we have $\pi(n)-\operatorname{li}(n)<-C\sqrt{n}\log\log\log n/\log n$. Either of these two statements contradicts my first display (which is implied by your proposed inequality). Please read the relevant parts of Montgomery-Vaughan's book

Comment: thank you - I don't fully understand Montgomery-Vaughan's approach, but I will persevere with it

Comment: ...btw what do you mean by "contradicts my first display"?

Comment: @martin: The word "display" means a displayed formula, i.e. a formula that appears centered in a seperate line of a mathematical text. My response contains only one such formula, namely the bound derived from your proposed inequality. Regarding Montgomery-Vaughan: the result is the last one in the book, so perhaps you need to read earlier parts of the book to follow it.

Comment: OK yes, I will read it all! ... I am very appreciative of your help here

Comment: Revisiting this, I am not sure that the first statement in my question does imply your first display, since $$\left|\operatorname{li}(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor}\dfrac{\pi(n^{1/k})}{k}\right|\ll|\operatorname{li}(n)-\pi(n)|$$
Am I just very confused?!

Comment: @martin: The inequality in your last comment is false. By Littlewood's result, the expression $\operatorname{li}(n)-\pi(n)$ changes sign infinitely often. At every sign change $n$, your right hand side is less than $2$, while the left hand side is $\gg n^{1/3}/\log n$. On the other hand, my first display does follow from your proposed inequality. See the "Added 2" section in my response for the details.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick response. I will need a little time to digest it though!

Comment: @martin: I had a mistake in the "Added 2" section (due to fast writing), it is corrected now.